# What is the truthfullness of the film "Revolution.com - USA: The Conquest of the East"?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, geopolitics

This is a Russian version of a French film from mid-2000s "Revolution.com"

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3QxDgft148

French version with Spanish subtitles:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqPQGVBBYlc

It shows how US government and government-sponsored NGOs organize "color revolutions" in several countries. Large part of the film (which does not deal with Russia proper) has been shown on Russian state TV. The film shows quite rare and unexpected footage which shows things I would not expect from a non-staged film.

- The film shows US and pro-US politicians and activists to openly explain their technique at overthrowing the governments and subverting the army. One US expat in Kyrgyzstan openly admits that it was his work to overthrow the government. The organizers of the color revolutions in different countries are shown to attend the same seminars organized by US special services. One episode shows a blackboard with a list of countries where revolutions are planned, with dates.
- The film shows quite surprising footage when the color-revolutionary activists from different countries discuss financial matters, divide funds and their spendings, admit loyalty to the United States. In some frames the leader of the Georgian revolution evidently appears under drugs. I do not know how it became possible to compel somebody to discuss money or appear intoxicated under camera. Still the frames do not seem to be made covertly.
- The film shows some events strikingly in-time, not post-factum. For example, It shows the details and mechanics of Kyrgyz revololution in motion, days before it and just after, and preparation to the Ukraininian revolution just two months before it happened, as if the creators of the film knew exactly the time when the revolution is to come, which suggests some prolonged (for years) coordination with perpetrators.
- It also shows some politicians in quite surprising situation, for example it shows McCain to abuse the Kyrgyz foreign minister by telephone just before the revolution and shows that minister just after the conversation saying that Kyrgyz people were not ready for democracy. It also shows Georgian president Saakashvili after his speech asking the US intelligence officer whether he said all correct, and an American expat who became a Georgian education minister after the revolution, admitting how much they spent for the revolution to come. In no frame the perpetrators make any objections to the shooting despite being shown unpleasantly and harshly accused by the narrator (for example McCain is directly accused in intervening in internal affairs of Kyrgyzstan for the cited call).

Given all the above I wonder how it became possible to make all those people not only agree for an interview but expose themselves in unpleasant situations to a group that is harshly critical of their actions, show them in the course of their real work, before, after and in the process and explain their covert intentions.

I also wonder why I nowhere could find not only an English version but also any reference to this film in English.

Given all the above I would ask

- Whether this film is staged and if yes, to what degree?
- Whether it is a hoax?
- Whether it is somehow fabricated?
- Why it is quite unknown?

**UPDATE** ***Some of the context***

- 15:30 Mike Stone from US state-funded organization Freedom House, 10 days before the revolution, shows a typography where they print 6 anti-government newspapers and a book on how to make revolutions "From Dictatorship to the Democracy" (which includes the technique on how to subvert the army). A plaque on the wall indicates "United States Bureau of Democracy". All the equipment shows the labeled that it is property of US government, namely, the mentioned United States Bureau of Democracy. Mike Stone says that he calls the revolutions "green" because of money they are paid with.
- 22:05 McCaine talks with the Kyrgyz minister by telephone, demanding they lift ban on the cited book on how to make the revolutions, and the minister promises to do so.
- 25:30 After the revolution, activist of Kyrgyz revolution admits the help of the USA
- 25:58 Mike Stone says overthrow of regimes is his work
- 28:40 Bob Helvi from Einstein Foundation who also publishes the book tells some advices from the book on how to subvert the army
- 53:40 Seminar on how to make revolutions, Ukraine, 2 months before the revolution, organized by McCane and Freedom House
- 32:40 - summer camp in Crimea, organized by Freedom House and seminar there.
- 35:28 new Miniter of education of Georgia, at the same time, Soros foundation representative. He says Soros foundation spent $300000 for the revolution.
- 39:00 Meeting between Georgian and Belorussian revolutionaires (Bakeria and Lybedko). Belorussian activist says the USA senate will give them several million dollars. A representative of an unnamed US organization (possibly, Soros foundation) says they will give them 4 million for taking the power.
- 40:08 Bruce Jackson, US intelligence officer in retire, who heads the "Foundation for Transitional Democracies" oversees a speech of Georgian president. The president asks him whether he said all correct.
- 43:00 Belorussian revolutionary leader Lybedko discusses money in McCaine's International Republican Institute. In this place there is t-shirt with a list of planned revolutions.
- 45:00 Bruce Jackson's headquarters in Washington. He meets with Georgian revolutionary leader Bakeria (who became advisor of Georgian president after revolution), and with two Russian anti-Putin activists who say they came to learn how to make revolutions. The narrator cites Bruce Jackson to say Russia is the next target for the revolution.

Comment: The french film is in fact called "États-Unis à la conquête de l'est". My french can't keep up with a whole hour of fast political speech, so I haven't seen it, and it doesn't seem to have an English version. However, the claims you make doesn't seem to be made, or at least not to such as an extent. I wonder if the Russian edit/translation hasn't changed and sharpened some of the claims. It seems to have been largely ignored at least outside Russia, and doesn't seem to make many much extra-ordinary claims at all. An English version would be good.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro what claims exactly seem not having place in the French version?

Comment: That the whole color-revolution spring was completely orchestrated by the US and that the US had planned a further series of revolutions in all of Russia, which clearly is the claims you seem to put forward above from the Russian language version of the film. Perhaps you are not intending to say that the film says this, but that it is your conjecture? Then I misunderstood.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro the whole film is about it. It shows US intelligence officer's appartments where the planning is conducted.

Comment: @Anixx And you think CIA would allow a French documentary maker to film in there, during the plannig? :-) At what time in the movie is this shown?

Comment: At how many minutes into the movie is the US Intelligence officers planning shown? (In the russian version linked above).

Comment: @Lennart Regebro I suggest you to look through the film rather than asking me. He is shown quite a long time along with the revolution perpetrators, Georgian president, and other US and non-US perpetrators are shown as well, revealing their activity.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro in this meeting Bruce Jackson says that the next target for the revolution is Russia. I did for you a great work, by looking the film through again.

Comment: @Anixx: Thanks for making such a list of claims. These concrete and detailed claims made it possible to answer a question that would otherwise been very hard to answer.

Comment: Just some extra context: The magazines printed are not "anti-government" per se, they are "pro-democracy" papers. Admittedly, in a dictatorship, the difference is minimal. ;-) The book they show is *not* how to make revolutions. It's a book about how move a dictatorship towards democracy. It's very good, I've read it, and it's available for free in many languages here: http://www.aeinstein.org/organizations98ce.html

Comment: @Lennart Regebro the magazines are anti-government, as the perpetrators admit. An example of their material: they depict the president's residence along with a house of a poor family so to claim it is the president who guilty that the family does not have money. I think similar contrasts are easy to find in any "democratic" country as well.

Comment: @Anixx I down-voted because it seems to me that your description of the documentary is not truthful. Many of the things you first said about it you have backed down from. I down-voted it because you clearly *want* to believe that the revolutions are in fact organized by the US government, and you hoped that this documentary would support this preconception of yours. It does not. Definitely not in the French version, and I've come to believe it doesn't do it in the Russian version either, but that this is just your wishful thinking.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro it is openly said so in the documentary, on multiple occasions, including by the perpetrators, and by narrator. By Lybedko, by Shevardnadze, by Jackson, by Freedom House activists.

Comment: @Anixx: Not in the French original version. See my answer.

Comment: The original: https://youtu.be/aPEO4hYZqbM

Comment: The original Film in French from "États-Unis à la conquête de l'est" seems to match Russian translation from "Revolution.com"

Answer (score 15):

**Summary: The claims Anixx makes about this film presents a completely false version of the events of the colour-revolutions. This version of events is also completely different from the version of events presented by the French documentary.**

I've looked at some of the detailed claims you make based on the Russian version.

> It shows US intelligence officer's appartments where the planning is conducted.

There is nothing like that in the French version. There are no US intelligence officers, and there is no US intelligence officers apartment.

> 15:30 Mike Stone from United States Bureau of Democracy

In the French version Mike Stone is claimed to be from the non-governmental organization "Freedom house". This claim seems corroborated by internet searches. He doesn't seem to be from the United States Bureau of Democracy or have anything to do with it.

> 25:58 Mike Stone says overthrow of regimes is his work

He says no such thing, and neither does the French narrator claim he does.

> 35:28 new Minister of education of Georgia, at the same time, Soros foundation representative. He says Soros foundation spent $300000 for the revolution.

In the French version he says he spend $300.000 for rock concerts, and TV ads to get youth to vote in the upcoming election. No claims are done that the Soros foundation spent any money in support of any revolution.

> 39:00 Meeting between Georgian and Belorussian revolutionaries. Belorussian activist says the USA senate will give them several million dollars. Soros representative says they will give them 4 million for taking the power.

In the French version, there is no Soros representative in that meeting. No-one says they will give anyone any money. The guy presented as a Georgian activist claims that the US Congress have decided to donate 4 million dollars to Georgia. I don't know on what basis he claims this, if any.

> 40:08 Bruce Jackson, US intelligence officer

The French version makes no claim that Bruce Jackson is a US intelligence officer. It does not call him a US intelligence officer, nor claims that he has ever been one. (Although, admittedly, [he has been one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Jackson_%28Project_on_Transitional_Democracies%29). But that's not relevant, because he wasn't one during the revolutions.)

> In this place there is t-shirt with a list of planned revolutions.

The French version does not present this list as a list if "planned revolutions". The idea that some organization that "creates revolutions" would put up a list of the revolutions it intends to do on a *t-shirt* is just ridiculous. It's a T-shirt celebrating the revolutions, and expressing **hope** of future revolutions. Nothing else.

> 45:00 Bruce Jackson's headquarters in Washington. He meets with Georgian revolutionary leader Bakeria (who became advisor of Georgian president after revolution), and with two Russian anti-Putin activists who say they came to learn how to make revolutions.

The two Russian democrats do not say they came to learn how to make revolutions.

> in this meeting Bruce Jackson says that the next target for the revolution is Russia.

Bruce Jackson says no such thing in English, or the French translation, although *the narrator* claims that it is Bruce Jackson's goal.

**Conclusion**

I think it's quite evident that your description of the French film is completely inaccurate. Assuming that you are describing the Russian translation correctly, this means that the Russian translation is a lie. That would mean that whoever decided to send this film on Russian TV decided to not translate, but grossly re-write the movie with the object to show the color-revolutions like something staged by the US government, when this is not what the original French documentary claims at all.

However, as we have seen from the comments, you are rapidly backing down from the claims you did. It seems that perhaps the Russian version of the documentary is an accurate translation, and that you have just invented or misunderstood most of these claims. Perhaps the truth is somewhere in between.

**So yes, this film, in the original French version seems to show a fairly accurate and non-controversial version of events**. It has not gained of lot of notice internationally simply because it doesn't say anything controversial.

The French documentary essentially shows how various non-governmental organizations helped and supported the democrats in these various countries. The version according to **you** presents the revolutions as US-financed coups d'etat. There is no support for anything like that in the French version.

Since I don't speak Russian, I can't judge if the version sent on Russian TV are making such claims or not, but since you have completely made up claims like this in another question, I suspect that it does not, and that your claims are based mostly on your over active misinterpretation of the documentary.